# Setting up visual studio 2010 for azure

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I have VS2010 Ultimate and i want to create a

> Windows Azure Project

However under Cloud templates i only have the

> Enable azure tools project

There's already have WindowsAzureTools installed, and IIS7.5, but still, there's no option to create an azure project

What else is needed to setup?

Comment: You need to install again as something didn't get configured correctly. Make sure to download the latest azure tools / sdk here -> http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install Windows Azure Tools go to the menu bar, choose File-> New->Project and then in installed templates select Visual C# or Visual Basic, and then choose a project template called Windows Azure Tools Enable.

Edit later: Start Visual Studio **as administrator**->File->New->Project->Choose project for Azure->Select the .net framework->In the Name text-box, type the name of your project->OK->now you have a 'New Project'of Windows Azure.

Comment: i did that. after the install i still recived Windows Azure Tools Enabl only. BTW this project points exactly to the same url that @AlanBarber posted

Comment: also the web platform installer says that i have the azure sdk installed

Comment: very strange., and documentation is scarce http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ee791955.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Windows Azure installation did not go through as expected and you only have Windows Azure SDK installed but "Windows Azure Authoring Tools" either failed to installed or you installed both of these components separately. To solve your problem first please uninstall all the Windows SDK components from your programs.

After that Please use the link below to install Windows Azure from Web Platform Installer (WebPI) and which will install all 4 components in your machine:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=234939&clcid=0x409

The list of components needed for successful Windows Azure SDK integration in Visual Studio is as below:
[image: Windows Azure SDK Components]